# what messages won't show when using -s for make command in c++?

Tags: c++, makefile

what messages won't be shown when using -s  for make command in c++?

if make -s only show warning or error info?

I tried change make file in eclipse's hello make file project and it has no difference.

07:49:32 **** Build of configuration Default for project TestMake ****
make all 
g++ -O2 -s -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0   -c -o TestMake.o TestMake.cpp
g++ -o TestMake.exe TestMake.o

07:49:53 Build Finished (took 21s.855ms)

```
07:51:50 **** Build of configuration Default for project TestMake ****
make all 
g++ -O2  -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0   -c -o TestMake.o TestMake.cpp
g++ -o TestMake.exe TestMake.o
```

07:51:51 Build Finished (took 732ms)

```
07:51:50 **** Build of configuration Default for project TestMake ****
make all 
g++ -O2  -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0   -c -o TestMake.o TestMake.cpp
g++ -o TestMake.exe TestMake.o 

07:51:51 Build Finished (took 732ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary)?

> ‘-s’
>     ‘--silent’
>     ‘--quiet’
>     Silent operation; do not print the recipes as they are executed.

So it won't show the recipes, but will show any other output, including warnings and errors.

Comment: @jiafu: Yes, the recipes are the commands executed by build rules.

Comment: @jiafu: As far as I can see, you added `-s` to the compiler arguments, not the make arguments. That won't do anything interesting.